# Kubuntu 16.04 <-> 15.10 Inconsistent and slow wirless network transfer speeds

Tags: networking, kubuntu, raid, transfer

I have a file server running Kubuntu 15.10 and a client running 16.04.  In truth, this issue existed prior to the 16.04 upgrade.  When moving files, say a 500MB folder of MP3s, the transfer rate gets as high as 100 KiB/s and then drops to zero every several seconds.  I need a few leads on how to fix this.  Below is the network topology:

Server:

- 3-WARE Escalade 9500S-4LP w/ 4 WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 in RAID 5a
- Intel DG965MQ Motherboard with Intel 82566DC (gigbit to the router)
- Netgear WNDR3700v2 Wifi Router
- Wireless connection via static IP (to this client) and WPA2-PSK

Client:

- TP-Link TL-WDN4800 – N900 Wireless Dual Band wireless card
- 120GB SATA3 Solid State Drive, Kingston, SV300S37A120G

It is not really direction dependent, as the transfer rate is pretty poor in either direction.  I have made the avahi-daemon fix in nsswitch.conf to not visible effect.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts and solutions to help this issue.  It has been around for a long time and I have lived with it, but now is a chance to fix it.

Comment: You're connecting over Wifi, radio signal interference could explain your issues. Try selecting different channels on the router; on my WNDR3800 it's "Advanced > Wireless Setup" and then try setting other channels for your 2.4 and 5.0 GHz bands.

Comment: Elliot, good call, sadly it did not help, furthermore, I plugged in an ethernet cable.. between the router and the client machine.. same result.  I tried moving a 1.4GB file between the RAID5 and a local disc on the Server, no issues.  No issue locally on the client either.  This points to a network issue of some kind, thoughts?

Comment: In the end, this seems to be an issue with the applet I was using to measure throughput speed.  I am getting about 50% saturation currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the KDE applet from the toolbar where you choose the network connections seems to be flaky.  I used the system monitor and could show ~50% network saturation during transfers in both directions.